# Помогите, пожалуйста, перевести с PascalABC.NET на Java

Tags: java, pascal, pascalabc.net

```
begin
 var n := ReadlnInteger;
  var max := 0;
  for var i := 1 to n do
  begin  
   var t := ReadSeqInteger(2).Min;
   if t > max then
      max := t;
  end;
 max.Println
end.
```

Comment: ...сессия близится...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть просьбы, на выполнение которых требуется так мало усилий, что просто не остается веских причин отказать человеку в помощи. Минусовать такие просьбы, на мой взгляд, это проявление жлобства.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int max = 0, n = in.nextInt();
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        int t = Math.min(in.nextInt(), in.nextInt());
        if (t > max) max = t;
    }
    System.out.println(max);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое

Comment: Рада, что смогла помочь)

Comment: А тут можно в личку написать?

Comment: Честно говоря, я не знаю. По-моему, нет. Можете написать в личку на Киберфоруме. Я там alicesmagic.

Comment: можете зайти http://www.cyberforum.ru/ms-access/thread2546651.html#post14063380?

Comment: @AliceMagic Это не жлобство, а простой контроль качества. Если бы такие ответы не уходили в минус, их было бы гораздо больше, а значит было бы больше вопросов типа "сделайте за меня домашку". Если бы ТС хотя бы написал решение на том языке, который знает, не грех помочь переписать его на другой язык, но код, приложенный к вопросу, тоже [не его](https://znanija.com/task/33598298)